# Unable acess dashboard after changing to https (error 400)

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I install Wordpress on google cloud platform(bitnami). 
When I changed site/home URL to https from settings, homepage is work but dashboard can not access even I enter the right username and password.
It show error 400. replying a posts is the same situation.

[image: log screenshot]

How do I fix it? Please help!

Comment: are you working in wordpress.org or wordpress.com?

Comment: do you have such kind of plugin **Hide My WordPress plugin**?

Comment: I'm working in wordpress.org and I don't install Hide My WordPress plugin.

Comment: are you using any cache plugin?

Comment: what are you using for https:// redirection?

Comment: I've installed Hyper Cache plugin but already not in use. 
I change I define site/home URL and add '(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; ? ' to wp-config.php

Answer (score -1):

1) check your plugin folder inside /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-conten/plugins/? It should has permissions 775 and bitnami/daemon as user and group.

2) Check the content of the Apache error log file? You can find it at /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log.

3) Disable plugin simply rename plugin folder and load admin and check is it login.After that active it one by one.

Comment: It shows a few lines like  [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 25442:tid 140085366179584] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client ip] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: url... in error_log

Comment: do you have htaccess inroot folder?

Comment: have you tried using a different browser or clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, now is deactivate all plugins. 
there is .htaccess on /opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/ , but it is made by myself.

Comment: Just move it outside the folder or rename it

Comment: and if I add IP to domain name in hosts file , the situation wouldn't happen.

Comment: can you give me link??

Comment: I have solution of your problem.make revert whatever you do.

Comment: '(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; ? ' Problem with this

Comment: If I remove this line, wp-login.php will show message " redirects you too many times... "

Comment: Let do I am say

Comment: Rename your htaccess file make it .htaccess.bak or something else

Comment: Now open private browser and open site admin

Comment: still keep loop in wp-admin page

Comment: do you use private browser?

Comment: did you add any custom redirection in functions.php file?

Comment: yes, I use private browser and  I edited js/css url in functions.php or page will break after redirecting to https.

Comment: can you revert all manual modifications.If you don't want then just rename your theme folder not remember themes